# How to get recent SVN revision numbers for completed builds in Buildbot using the master.cfg file?

Tags: svn, buildbot

I'm looking for a method or sample code to get previous completed SVN revision numbers based on the Builder name.  My purpose is to use the difference of the numbers to query SVN and create a report for changes made for a build.

Answer (score 2):

Each build already has the SVN revision that it used ("got_revision"). You can use that directly from the Build's status.

If you just want the last build on that Builder, you can query the builder for the last build.  The build status has 'getLastFinishedBuild' to help with that.